# kinit: invalid UID in persistent keyring name while getting default ccache while using Ansible

Tags: ansible, kerberos

Let me start with a short description:
Target host: RHEL7, kernel 3.10, Python2.7

On the target host, there is a perl script (run by a particular user) which, among others, does stuff like:

```
kdestroy -A
kinit user@domain -kt path_to_keytab
```

While on the host I can perform (as the 'scriptrunner' user) all commands without error. Yet, while using ansible I get 'kinit: invalid UID in persistent keyring name while getting default ccache' error.

The playbook is run from AnsibleTower with credentials using 'sudo' escalation mode and playbook itself uses become: yes and become_user: scriptrunner so the user is the same when running the commands from terminal.

I have tried running commands with command module, just

```
command: /bin/kdestory -A and
command /bin/kinit someuser@domain -kt path_to_keytab.
```

I have also tried running the whole script as:
command: /bin/bash -c -l thescript.sh. the result is always the same.

Why so? Any Ideas?

Comment: Troubleshooting suggestion:  write a small wrapper script that dumps the shell environment to a file under /tmp and invokes the Perl script.  Once you have it working with an interactive login, leave the last file written in /tmp and have Ansible connect and invoke the script.  Then examine the differences.  My guess is there's an environment variable missing from the Ansible sessions, or the `$PATH` is finding a different `kdestroy` / `kinit`.

Comment: @SottoVoce Your advice turned out to be of gold:)
Ansible user had totally different set of ENV variables, infamous KRB5CCNAME among them. Adding source ~/.bashrc && unset KRB5CCNAME solved the problem.:)
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If running `unset KRB5CCNAME` did not resolve it, you can create a temporary Kerberos credential cache, which might be required before using kinit or klist for the first time:

```
export KRB5CCNAME=`mktemp`
```

If that doesn't work, try to change the value of "default_ccache_name" in `/etc/krb5.conf` to a local file:

```
[libdefaults]
# ...
# default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
  default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
```